# Solving a basic equation $v_{1}x+v_{2}y+v_{3}z=w$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following vectors: 
$$v_{1}=(2,1,-1),\,v_{2}=(-m,-1,3),\,v_{3}=(-3,2,m+1),w=(m+1,m,-1)$$

And I'm trying to understand for which $m\in \mathbb{R}$ we get $v_{1}x+v_{2}y+v_{3}z=w$.

In order to determinate it, I tried to solve the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & -m & -3 & m+1\\ 1 & -1 & 2 & m\\ -1 & 3 & m+1 & m-1 \end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & m\\ 2 & -m & -3 & m+1\\ -1 & 3 & m+1 & m-1 \end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & m\\ 0 & -m+2 & -7 & -m+1\\ 0 & 2 & m+3 & 2m-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

then I changed $m=2$ and I got:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & -7 & -1\\
0 & 2 & 5 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\overset{R_{2}\leftrightarrow R_{3}}{\to}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 5 & 3\\
0 & 0 & -7 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

meaning its has a solution.
Then I assumed that $m\neq 2$, so we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & m\\
0 & -m+2 & -7 & -m+1\\
0 & 2 & m+3 & 2m-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

But now I'm not sure what to do next. how should I continue from here?

Comment: Continue reducing the matrix, of course. If you don’t want to divide by $2-m$, then swap the second and third rows.